# How to specify what is printed to silkscreen layer in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad, silkscreen

I am finishing up a PCB design for the first time in Eagle, and I need to know how to print the component names onto the silkscreen layer, how to I set the layers up so the right things are printed?

Comment: Google "eagle silkscreen". Works for me.

Comment: Designators should be a part of the footprint in the library. You shouldn't have to add them manually

Comment: Which design layers end up in which gerber file is controlled by the CAM processor.  For fabs that offer to just take your .brd file (OSHPark, etc) allowing you to skip running the CAM job yourself, they usually have some sane defaults that are documented or even a preview tool which will show you what you get - but they'll typically also take gerbers if you want more control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

[image]

`[t/b]Place` is the default for part outlines.
`[t/b]Names` is the default for component names (U1, R5, etc.)
`[t/b]Values` is the default for component values (PIC16F1454, 10k, etc.)
`[t/b]` is top or bottom layer.

---

Don't know why it was voted to close as "too broad" and "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Voted to be closed because it shows zero research effort. In the lack of proper categorization, too broad or unclear is used.

Comment: Oh.  Maybe we need an "other" reason then, if it won't be abused.